# Choosing the best point from a logarithmic function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I bring a chart with me (ignore the blue irregularities):

[image]

I want to find a value on the $x$-axis which would give me the largest distance value while keeping time as low as possible. How would I go about doing it?

I was thinking about using derivatives, but, since we studied them last year, I cannot remember a thing about them.

Comment: Thanks for embedding the image, I couldn't do it as a new member

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to decide exactly how you would like to trade off between "largest distance value" and "time as low as possible". How to decide that depends entirely on why you're trying to do this in the first place, so I can't answer that for you.

The most obvious thing to do would be find the maximum value of their ratio, i.e. distance/time. If you did that, you could find the maximum value directly from the data by just dividing one by the other at each point. But, you might want to use the smoothed values (which you seem to have) instead of the raw values, and you may wish to skip some of the first few values where both d and t are close to zero.

If you so happen to have fitted functions d(x) and t(x) to the data, then you could find the maximum value of d(x)/t(x) analytically by calculating the derivative of d(x)/t(x), and testing all of the points where that derivative is equal to zero. But it's probably not any less work than just calculating (or more to the point getting a computer to calculate) the value at each point and taking the highest one.

Comment: I have no idea why I didn't think of that, finding the largest difference between distance and time seems like the easiest solution, thank you very much!

Comment: Largest difference between distance and time is very badly defined! You are subtracting things with different units! It would actually mean you are maximizing  (x-k*t) where k could be the "importance" of time with respect to x (and it would have the units of velocity). And by choosing a different k (stretching one graph with respect to the other), you can get anything, you may even get a zero where you had a maximum before. You need a much better criterion than that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's a good idea to fit some reasonable function on this data so you get rid of irregularities. Don't calculate derivatives from point data if you can avoid it, because this process amplifies noise. I would  fit a quadratic function to time and maybe a square root (unless some other root happens to fit perfectly) plus some low degree polynomial for the position. Like $a\sqrt{u}+b+cu+du^2$ where $u$ is the horizontal coordinate (whatever it is).

Now for the hard part. You need to put your criterion into math. If physics or strict and clear requirements don't give you a well defined function to maximize, you need to put your intuition into some simple mathematical form.

We need a function $f(x,t)$ which has a maximum where your condition is satisfied the most. Any function that looks like $x-vt$ will probably be a bad one, unless your physics tells you you are measuring the distance between a constant speed motion at time $t$ and position $x$. The choice of $v$ is an arbitrary tuning parameter and you have no idea what it could be (and choosing it differently, it can give a completely different result). It might work if $v$ is very very small (that just means that you want "maximum x, but... try to avoid high t, if you can, but it's not that big a deal".

Coupling terms are usually product/division terms. If you take $f(x,t)=x/t$, you are just maximizing average velocity. That's probably fine (as Steven said in his answer). Alternatively, you can ask for the highest instantaneous velocity. This is trickier, because your "time" and "distance" are both expressed with some other parameter that I called $u$ before. It would be $f(x,t)=(dx/du)/(dt/du)$. If you have an analytical fit, you can find the maximum of this function.

If $x$ and $t$ are not actually distance and time for motion of an object, but independent measurements, then you need a function that generally increases with $x$ but decreases with time. Division like $x/t$ is a bit problematic because of $t=0$ problems, so you can also do something like $x e^{-kt}$ where $k$ is how badly you want to avoid higher $t$.

However, looking at your data... you may be asking the wrong questions. If the distance saturates at some maximum value, then you have a clearly defined scale what's big and what's not. I would just say "take the time when distance reaches 75% of final value" or something like that. This is much more robust, and will give consistent results even if your behaviour changes a lot. This would be my best suggestion, but of course, because I don't know what exactly your data means and what you are trying to do, I cannot judge what is the best choice.